# How to detect if parent activity has been instantiated?

Tags: android, android-navigation

In my activity, I have:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ChildActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
</activity>
```

**ChildActivity** can be accessed via a standard launcher icon on the device.

My problem is when the user accesses **ChildActivity** via the launcher icon, then presses the **Up** button in the action bar, the app exits rather than going up to **ParentActivity**. This is because ParentActivity hasn't been instantiated.

Not sure if it's the best way, but I am trying to solve the problem by overriding `onSupportNavigateUp()`. However, I don't know how I can detect if the parent activity has been instantiated:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {

    boolean hasParentActivityBeenInstantiated = ???;

    if (hasParentActivityBeenInstantiated) {

        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    else {

        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        startActivity(upIntent);
        finish();
        return true; // Up navigation completed successfully and this Activity was finished.
    }
}
```

So how can I determine if the parent activity has been instantiated? More importantly, in this case, is overriding `onSupportNavigateUp()` the right way to navigate to the parent activity?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to guess if parent activity is instantiated or not, but use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for parent activity. I think it is also fine to use onSupportNavigateUp unless you refactor your app to be single-activity with single navigation graph. Imo navigation framework leaves no choices for multi activity setup.

If for some fancy reason you need to explicitly know if it's up, you can use various techniques including static field initialization, flagging some field inside the application instances etc.

---

I did similar implementation (kotlin) and I was using onBackPressed for the purpose but it probably doesn't suite your situation (I was handling all the descendant fragments sys back press) however I would suggest using `TaskStackBuilder` if your depth of child/parent is bigger then one:

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val upIntent: Intent? = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this)

        checkNotNull(upIntent) { "No parent activity intent" }

        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
            .startActivities()

        finish()
    }
```

Comment: I cannot understand why we should start an activity that as a parent as default activity.
Wouldn't be better that the other activity is the child of this one that is openend as first one?

Comment: For example if deep linking is involved. Or direct shortcut (as I believe in question above).

Comment: Yhe only with a shortcut situation it could be happen